# Radio button doesn't reset to initial

Tags: html, css, radio-button, material-design-lite

I have the following radio buttons which share the same `name` :

```
<div id="main_div">
    <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="radio1">
        <input type="radio" id="radio1" class="mdl-radio__button" name="somename" value="1" checked>
        <span class="mdl-radio__label">Radio 1</span>
    </label>
    <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="radio2">
        <input type="radio" id="radio2" class="mdl-radio__button" name="somename" value="2">
        <span class="mdl-radio__label">Radio 2</span>
    </label>
    <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="radio3">
        <input type="radio" id="radio3" class="mdl-radio__button" name="somename" value="3">
        <span class="mdl-radio__label">Radio 3</span>
    </label>
    <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="radio4">
        <input type="radio" id="radio4" class="mdl-radio__button" name="somename" value="4">
        <span class="mdl-radio__label">Radio 4</span>
    </label>
    <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="radio5">
        <input type="radio" id="radio5" class="mdl-radio__button" name="somename" value="5">
        <span class="mdl-radio__label">Radio 5</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

I can't make a fidle of it beacause, I need to change the page and go back.

When I check for example the radio `radio3` and go the next page using a link and then click on the browser to go back. My radio `radio3` button is still  checked but I gave by default the `radio1` the attribute `checked` so I think the `radio1` should be checked.

I saw in the label in the `radio3` the following class `is-checked` but the input isn't checked.

I'm using material design lite (https://getmdl.io/)

Comment: If you click on the browser back button it will get the page in its last state before you got redirected.

Comment: Oh okay didn't know that, because my radio button `input` isn't checked

Comment: what do you mean with "because my radio button input isn't checked"?

Comment: Well my `radio1` is checked by default, but if I change it to `radio4` for eg. and change page and go back. The `radio4` is checked but If I look throught the console the input isn't checked

Comment: If you mean that you inspect the element and don't see the :checked attribute on the element you clicked than this is correct it doesnt update the attribute in the DOM

Comment: But when I'm getting the value of the checked radio I'm getting the `radio1` value and not the "visually" checked radio. I'm getting the value with `var value = $('input[name=somename]:checked').val();`

Comment: Oh that is not expected, you could try the answer that @Ben C just posted?

Comment: @NicoShultz Yup just tried and it's working as expected, thanks for the commenting :)

Comment: No problem :) glad it is resolved

Comment: Your code runs fine on Google Chrome. Support of autocomplete on <input type="radios"/> aren't supported by all browsers as well as W3C. Google Chrome not supports it and code runs fine without adding it . Firefox has like autocomplete="on" as default.
Check this documentation.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can prevent the browser from "remembering" the state of your radio buttons by adding `autocomplete="off"` to your `<input>` elements. This should make your page show the first radio as checked each time.

```
<input type="radio" value="xxx" autocomplete="off">
```

[Read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete)

Comment: Support of autocomplete on <input type="radios"/> aren't supported by all browsers as well as W3C. Google Chrome not supports it and code runs fine without adding it . Firefox has like autocomplete="on" as default.
Check this documentation.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp